# Keyerror while editing openapi schema for FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi

I have written the below code to edit code samples in redoc of FastAPI:

```
def custom_openapi():
    # cache the generated schema
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    # custom settings
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Test API",
        version="0.0.1",
        description=description,
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    # setting new logo to docs
    openapi_schema["info"]["x-logo"] = {
        "url": "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/img/logo-margin/logo-teal.png"
    }
    api_uri_list = ["/url1", "/url2", "/url3", "/url4"]

    for uri in api_uri_list:
        openapi_schema["paths"][str(uri)]["get"]["x-codeSamples"] = [
            {
                'lang': 'NodeJS',
                'source': 'const http = require("http")\n'
                          'http.get("' + uri + '", res => {\n'
                                                                       'console.log(res.data)',
                'label': 'NodeJS'
            },
            {
                'lang': 'Python',
                'source': 'import requests\n'
                          'response = requests.get("' + uri + '")\n'
                                                                                      'print(response.text())',
                'label': 'Python'
            },
        ]
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema

app.openapi = custom_openapi()
```

But whenever I am trying to execute this, I am getting below error:

```
Process SpawnProcess-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 59, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 66, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 471, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\Desktop\TestAPI\run.py", line 1, in <module>      
    from app.main import app
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\Desktop\TestAPI\app\main.py", line 110, in <module>
    app.openapi = custom_openapi(app, description)
  File "C:\Users\Aadhi\Desktop\TestAPI\app\main.py", line 24, in custom_openapi
    openapi_schema["paths"][str(uri)]["get"]["x-codeSamples"] = [
KeyError: '/url1'
```

Previously it was working fine but while optimizing the code, I got one error, after that I reverted the changes but this issue remain persistent. Not sure what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Have you printed `openapi_schema` to see if it actually contains those keys?  Or, do you need `openapi_schema['paths'][uri] = {'get': {}}` to initialize things first?

Comment: @TimRoberts I had printed the openapi schema and paths were empty 'paths': {}.  May be these required to be initialize first. But I ain't sure how it was working before as I didn't initialize before as well.

Comment: Are you calling `custom_openapi()` before or after creating your API routes?

Comment: @M.O. now I called it after all the API routes and its working fine but when I am trying to load my redoc page, its 500 error and then I checked the error in the logs, so there was like: File "C:\Users\Aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 231, in openapi
    return JSONResponse(self.openapi())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: If you replace `app.openapi = custom_openapi()` with `app.openapi = custom_openapi` (no parentheses - as in the [examples](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/?h=extend#override-the-method) in the docs), does it resolve the issue?

Comment: @Helen yeah it resolved the issue. Actually I had defined the custom_openapi function in some other file and passed app as parameter to the method, due to which I was getting this error. Now I defined the function in the main file only and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below code snippet in the end of file and replace custom_openapi() with custom_openapi, resolved the issue for me:

```
app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

Or else if you don't want to define it, in the end of the file, then intialize the variable with the required key, but this way you can loose lot of CSS from the redoc file:

```
for uri in api_uri_list:
        openapi_schema['paths'][uri] = {'get': {}}
        openapi_schema["paths"][str(uri)]["get"]["x-codeSamples"] = [
            {
                'lang': 'NodeJS',
                'source': 'const http = require("http")\n'
                          'http.get("' + uri + '", res => {\n'
                                                                       'console.log(res.data)',
                'label': 'NodeJS'
            },
            {
                'lang': 'Python',
                'source': 'import requests\n'
                          'response = requests.get("' + uri + '")\n'
                                                                                      'print(response.text())',
                'label': 'Python'
            },
        ]
```